# WPF/silverlight - Is there any simple 2D Game/Physics engine recommend?

Tags: silverlight

I would start to write WPF and Silverlight 2D game, i would to find some game engine library,the only one i found on google is FarseerPhysics  ( http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics) and seem quite good. But is there any other recommend for starter?

And one more question is is it any alternate software of expression blend for create Silverlight UI?

Comment: WPF and Silverlight or really just Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also the [Physics Helper for Silverlight, WPF, Blend, and Farseer](http://www.codeplex.com/PhysicsHelper).

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) is a lightweight XAML editor with split view.